# ipad app wierd behavior

Tags: ios, ipad

My ipad project is master-detail view based. There is a button on detail view's toolbar, when user tap on the button, it popup a popover view to show four buttons (as menu). Three of buttons' actions are like the following (the three buttons show three different model form sheets):

```
- (void) showOnlineSgf
{
    NSLog(@"showOnlineSgf");
    TGOOnlineSgfViewController *dlg =
    [[TGOOnlineSgfViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TGOOnlineSgfViewController"
                                                 bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:dlg];

    [nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
    dlg = nil;
    nav = nil;
}
```

The other button's action is to show a MFMailComposeViewController. Code is like the following:

```
- (void) emailCurrentGame
{
    NSLog(@"email current game");
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    picker = nil;
}
```

The weird behavior is that when I tap the button what should execute showOnlineSgf(), but emailCurrentGame() is actually executed. When I set a breakpoint in showOnlineSgf(), it's hit, and step by step, each statement in showOnlineSgf() is executed. But the result on screen is a MFMainComposeViewController shows up.

I know this question is hard to answer. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: @BorisProhaska and zeiteisen Thanks for your comment. It hit the problem. I didn't ever realize that one event might connect to multiple IBAction. And zeiteisen said the truth, I copy pasted one button in IB, that caused the button has two connections. You two could move your comment to answer, then I can upvote you. Also I'll accept Boris's answer, because it's 1 minute early than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your outlet connection of your `UIButton` that triggers `showOnlineSgf`. Most likely you copy pasted your `UIButton` in Interface Builder, which causes it to copy its assigned action as well. Then you've connected your other action, resulting in your `UIButton` having two actions.

To resolve the problem, simply disconnect your `UIButton` that triggers `showOnlineSgf` from the `emailCurrentGame` action.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you copy pasted in the interface builder an already connected button. Check if the button has more than one action assigned.